# Sum of two sequences of independent random variables

Tags: probability, expected-value, independence

Given the mutually independent rv $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$, I want to show that $(X_1+Y_1),(X_2+Y_2)$ are independent as well. Is it sufficient to show that $$E((X_1+Y_1)(X_2+Y_2))=E(X_1+Y_1)E(X_2+Y_2)$$?

Comment: If your assumption is that the random variables are two-by-two independent then the conclusion is false. If they are jointly independent then  it is **not** enough to verify that the product of the expectations is the expectaion of the product.

Comment: Yes they are jointly independent... $X_1,X_2,Y_1,Y_2$ are iid. What would be the right way to show the independence of the sums?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual proof applies measure theory. Using the notion of independent $\sigma$-algebras, you can prove that if

$$\{X_i:i \in I\}$$ is a collection of independent random variables, and $\{I_j: j \in J\}$ is a collection of disjoint subsets of $I$, then the collections of  random variables

$$\{X_i: i \in I_j\}, j\in J$$

are also independent.

Putting $X_3:= Y_1, X_4:= Y_2$ and $I= \{1,2,3,4\}$, we get that

$$\{X_1, X_3\}, \{X_2,X_4\}$$

are independent collections. This means that $\sigma(X_1, X_3)$ and $\sigma(X_2, X_4)$ are independent. Since

$$\sigma(X_1 + X_3) \subseteq \sigma(X_1, X_3)$$
$$\sigma(X_2 + X_4) \subseteq \sigma(X_2, X_4)$$

we also get that the $\sigma$-algebras $\sigma(X_1+X_3)$ and $\sigma(X_2 + X_4)$ are independent. This means that the random variables

$$X_1+X_3 = X_1+Y_1$$

and $$X_2 + X_4 = X_2 + Y_2$$

are independent.

Comment: I get the part about the independent collections, we called it the "Blocklemma" in our measure theory course. But how do you get from there to the independent summs?

Comment: I added some details. Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: First of all thank you very much! Last question would be why $\sigma(X_1 + X_3) \subseteq \sigma(X_1, X_3)$?

Comment: $\sigma(X_1+X_3)$ is the smallest sigma algebra such that $X_1+X_3$ is measurable. Similarly, $\sigma(X_1,X_3)$ is the smallest sigma-algebra such that both $X_1, X_3$ are measurable. Since $X_1$ and $X_3$ are both $\sigma(X_1, X_3)$-measurable, their sum $X_1 + X_3$ is $\sigma(X_1,X_3)$-measurable. By minimality, we then get $\sigma(X_1+X_3) \subseteq \sigma(X_1,X_3)$.

Comment: this is just great, thank you so much!

Comment: You are welcome! I am glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

An elementary proof of independence is a bit lengthy but if you are familiar with characteristic functions you can prove this easily: You only have to show that $Ee^{i[t(X_1+Y_1)+s(X_2+Y_2)]}=Ee^{i[t(X_1+Y_1)]}Ee^{is[X_2+Y_2)]}$ for all real numbers $t$ and $s$. Can you show this?